# cumulative count and sum based on date frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df`, that, once sorted by date, looks like this:

```
   User       Date  price
0     2 2020-01-30     50
1     1 2020-02-02     30
2     2 2020-02-28     50
3     2 2020-04-30     10
4     1 2020-12-28     10
5     1 2020-12-30     20
```

I want to compute, for each row:

1. the number of row in the last month, and
2. the sum price in the last month.

On the example above, the output that I'm looking for:

```
   User       Date  price  NumlastMonth  Totallastmonth
0     2 2020-01-30     50             0               0
1     1 2020-02-02     30             0               0  # not 1, 50 ???
2     2 2020-02-28     50             1              50
3     2 2020-04-30     10             0               0
4     1 2020-12-28     10             0               0
5     1 2020-12-30     20             1              10  # not 0, 0 ???
```

I tried this, but the result is for all last row not only last month.

```
   df['NumlastMonth'] = data.sort_values('Date')\
        .groupby(['user']).amount.cumcount() 
   df['NumlastMonth'] = data.sort_values('Date')\
        .groupby(['user']).amount.cumsum()
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the output there is no 30/12/2020 in the input, also which date is this: 30/02/2020? Also can you explain your output a bit more?

Comment: Yep , ur right , i changed it

Comment: Can you add how you are generating this dataframeA, to make it easier to replicate your exact scenario

Comment: Just another thing what day is 30/02/2020 supposed to be, there is no 30 of February

Comment: Is the totallastmonth for 28/02/2020 correct? I mean 50, isn't it supposed to be 30?

Comment: no its 50 , its group by user , so only row user 2

Comment: Then why the output is `1      30/12/2020    20      1                10` for the user 1 at month 12?

Comment: because we have one row in the last month  which is  : 1      28/12/2020    10

Comment: why is `02/02/2020`'s output showing `(0, 0)` and why is it different than the result for `28/02/2020`?

Comment: also, I don't enjoy sorting dataframes by date in my head.

Comment: Yes but you also have 1 date and the result is the same, I really don't get it. perhaps is better if you explain the results in your question

Answer (score 0):

Taking literally the question (acknowledging that the example doesn't *quite* match the description of the question), we could do:

```
tally = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).agg({'User': 'count', 'price': sum})
tally.index += pd.offsets.Day(1)
tally = tally.reindex(index=df.Date, method='ffill', fill_value=0)
```

On your input, that gives:

```
>>> tally
            User  price
Date                   
2020-01-30     0      0
2020-02-02     1     50
2020-02-28     1     50
2020-04-30     0      0
2020-12-28     0      0
2020-12-30     0      0
```

After that, it's easy to change the column names and concat:

````
df2 = pd.concat([
    df.set_index('Date'),
    tally.rename(columns={'User': 'NumlastMonth', 'price': 'Totallastmonth'})
], axis=1)

# out:
            User  price  NumlastMonth  Totallastmonth
Date                                                 
2020-01-30     2     50             0               0
2020-02-02     1     30             1              50
2020-02-28     2     50             1              50
2020-04-30     2     10             0               0
2020-12-28     1     10             0               0
2020-12-30     1     20             0               0
​```
````